# Why is Perl not doing the math here?

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I have an array of hash references:

```
my @price = (
    {
        id    => '1',
        label => 5.00
    },
    {
        id    => '2',
        label => 7.50
    },
);
```

I also have 2 variable integers, $diff and $last. when I try to iterate over the array to multiply the "label" by `$diff/$last`:

```
foreach (@price) {
    print "(($diff/$last)*$_->{label})\t";
}
```

i get the following output:

```
((12/30)*5.00)
((12/30)*7.50)
```

I assume it is not multiplying because I have two integers and a hash reference. If this is correct, how can I make the hash reference an integer? How can I force Perl to actually do the math and print the resulting product?

Comment: Lesson to be learned: interpolation is not evaluation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not multiplying because all of that is inside the double quotes. You need to do:

```
print( (($diff/$last)*$_->{label}) . "\t" );
```

The way you're doing it perl is simply interpolating the variables and printing their values because they are enclosed within the quotes. The `*` is simply treated as a character to print. The above does the math then the `.` causes a concatenation to `"\t"` (which converts the result to a string).

```
$a = 5;
$b = 6;
print "$a + $b\n";
print $a + $b . "\n";
```

Outputs:

> 5 + 6
>   11

Comment: Your code didn't quite work. The tab was never printed. Changed `print(...) . "\t"` to `print((...) . "\t")`.

Comment: Don't use `$a` and `$b` as var names. You'll notice that the lack of a `my` variable escapes `strict` and `warnings` because `$a` and `$b` are supposed to be used inside `sort` blocks

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried:

```
foreach (@price) {
  $res = ($diff/$last)*$_->{label};
  print "$res\t";
}
```

i.e., compute it outside of the quotes so it isn't interpreted as a string.

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend evaluating a complex expression like this *inside* interpolating strings, but  you can do it two ways. Before I show you that, let me tell you how interpolation works. It's mainly meant to allow you to string *variables* in with literals without much fuss.

```
(( $diff / $last ) * $_->{label} )
```

is not a variable, it's an *expression*. However, the hash index `$_->{label}` is also an expression, although a simpler one, mainly concerned with *indexing* a variable to find a value stored within. The difference is that the whole thing is several operations and it not an attempt to display already stored data.

However, because the interpolation logic had to *parse* sometimes complicated expressions, you can interpolate almost any expression--if it is "phrased" as an indexing or dereference.

You can do the expression dereference:

```
print "${\(($diff/$last)*$_->{label})}\t";
```

Here, you 1) resolve the expression and 2) take a reference to its location in memory, and then 3) *dereference* that section of memory. So it's like dereferencing, only with computation.

There is also the literal array interpolation:

```
print "@{[ \(($diff/$last)*$_->{label}) ]}\t";
```

Here, you create a literal array with one member whose value is the expression and you deference that to have array interpolation take over.

Again, these are in no sense valid as part of a code base that will have to live over several years. However, they are cheap and dirty tricks that Perl's expressive power allows.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't do the math for the same reason

```
print "Now at 1/2 price, buy 5!\n";
```

does not output

Now at .5 price, buy 120

(if only perl would use '!' to mean 'factorial' :-)